# QEMU runs but the output screen doesn't show up

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

When I used my distribution's version of QEMU (which was 2.6 I believe), everything worked well, all my VM's started. I downloaded QEMU's source and compiled it, and used `make install` to install. Now that I'm on 2.8, I don't see the window. It seems everything works, I get the same output in my terminal that I did before, but there's no new window with the graphical output.

I downloaded 2.7 and compiled and installed again, but it didn't work. Just to be sure that I'm on the right version, I verified using `--version`.

I would settle for either uninstalling the version of QEMU I compiled, or getting it to work, but I can't figure out how to do either.

Comment: When compiling QEMU run `./configure --help` which will give you options for enabling/disabling features like the GUI (I believe it has a GTK as well as an SDL variant), make sure you at least enable one of them, `make` it and try again.

Comment: Thank you! That did it. Mind answering so I can accept?

Comment: @AndréBorie Also, would you happen to know how I can connect virt-manager to this installation? I looked through all the options under `./configure --help`, but couldn't find anything preventing being able to connect to QEMU. Thanks again for you help!

Answer (score 1):

As @AndréBorie said in his comment, you need to compile QEMU with GTK support. Use `./configure --help` to see the options.